# Python, OpenCV: unable to make custom LBP cascade using opencv_traincascade

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, classification, image-recognition

I am using opencv 2.4.4 installed via macports with python 2.7.5 on a mac os x 10.7.5.

I want to train a cascade to look for male frontal faces. But I am getting the `terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6` error. I request the SO community help me figure out what might be going wrong.

The negative (background) image are taken from google: googleImages_noFaces (293 images)

The positive images are taken from Karolinska database: trainingSet (70 images)

I created a text file which indicates the relative location of background images: bgDesc.txt

I also created a text file indicating the relative location, number of positive instances in the image (which is always 1) and bounding region of the object (which is the entire image): maleDesc.txt

All these files can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2AJ7rliSQubNDBNU1NZV2lpWlU&usp=sharing).

The organization of the files is in this form:

```
/trainingSet
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
    .
    .
    .

/googleImages_noFaces
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
    .
    .
    .

/cascadeFiles

maleDesc.txt
bgDesc.txt
```

when I use opencv_createsamples a `maleDesc.vec` file is successfully created with the following line:

```
opencv_createsamples -vec maleDesc.vec -info maleDesc.txt -bg bgDesc.txt -num 70 -w 24 -h 24
```

if I use `-show` parameter I can see that 24x24 pixel images are created.

I then try

```
opencv_traincascade -data cascadeFiles -vec maleDesc.vec -bg bgDesc.txt -numPos 70 - numNeg 293 -numStages 1 -precalcValBufSize 500 -precalcIdxBufSize 500 -featureType LBP -w 24 -h 24
```

Which gives me an error.

I have tried different values of `-numPos` such as 10, 20 and so on up to 70 along with different values of `-numNeg` as 30, 60 and so on up to 293. I have tried to use numPos values that are less than numNeg values and even those which are greater than. I have also tried different `-numStages` values like 1, 5, 10, 20 and 100 but in all of these attempts I get the same error.

I have not tried different values of -minHitRate, -maxFalseAlarmRate, -weightTrimRate, -maxDepth, -maxWeakCount because I don't really understand how they influence the behavior of opencv_traincascade algorithm.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `terminate called throwing an exceptionAbort trap: 6` error was due to a typo. i managed to replicate the behavior and verify it in the bellow code

opencv_traincascade -data cascadeFiles -vec maleDesc.vec -bg bgDesc.txt -numPos 70 **- numNeg** 293 -numStages 1 -precalcValBufSize 500 -precalcIdxBufSize 500 -featureType LBP -w 24 -h 24

there was a space between `-` and `numNeg` which should have been `-numNeg`

additionally, the training proceeds even with very low samples but the numPos must be twice of numNeg

refer to this SO answer for more clarification on the haar and lbp training process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16834901/1463143

two weeks and 50 reputation as bounty got wasted because of a typo :|

Answer (score -4):

me helped compile OpenCV a function TBB [how to do opencv_traincascade on Ubuntu](http://ubuntu-wine.ru/publ/ubuntu_zapisnaja_knizhka/ubuntu_opencv_obuchenie_kaskadnogo_klassifikatora/2-1-0-34/)

sizes negative images (width & height) > positive samples

Comment: Thank you for your link. It was in Russian and I used google translate, it had an explanation similar to the [opencv doc for traincascade](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html). And what I tried is same as the procedure suggested in the docs and the link you shared which, still doesn't work for me. But I didn't understand the first part of your comment. Are you suggesting that I compile opencv with TBB?

Comment: sizes negative images (width & height) > sizes positive samples